# How to add a master node to the kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I set up a kubernetes cluster. And I want to add a master node to the cluster. my cluser version is 1.17.0 . what's the join command is? i can't find  Related docs about the command on the official website.

Comment: How are you doing the Cluster setup? Is it kubeadm/kubespray/kops  etc ?

Comment: @shashank kubeadm

Comment: @Esc does the solution provided below by shashank tyagi is working properly for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To join another master follow the below steps:

1. Generate the certificate key

   > `kubeadm alpha certs certificate-key`
2. Print the join command

   > `kubeadm token create --print-join-command`
3. Add the following flags to the above join command

   > `--control-plane --certificate-key "Certificate-key from step 1"`
4. Command should look like below

   > `sudo kubeadm join 192.168.0.200:6443 --token 9vr73a.a8uxyaju799qwdjv --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:7c2e69131a36ae2a042a339b33381c6d0d43887e2de83720eff5359e26aec866 --control-plane --certificate-key f8902e114ef118304e561c3ecd4d0b543adc226b7a07f675f56564185ffe0c07`

Comment: enough only 2 and 4 steps